# How to work with multiple chart.js charts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

building a simple webpage with 3 line charts from using chart.js.
I`m using all of them with line this:

```
var currentAmpChart;
currentAmpChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('amperageChart').getContext('2d'), {
```

and all of them have different ids: 'amperageChart', 'wattageChart' and 'voltageChart' in .html file.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="chart-container">
            <canvas id="polarChart" width="300em" height="300em"></canvas>
            <canvas id="voltageChart" width="300em" height="300em" aria-label="voltLabel" role="img"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="middle-content">
            <div class="th_data">
                <div id="temp">
                    <span id="temperature">20°C</span>
                    <img id="th_img" src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/thermo.svg')}}" alt="Temperature SVG"/>
                </div>
                <div id="hum">
                    <img id="th_img" src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/humid.svg')}}" alt="Humidity SVG"/>
                    <span id="humidity">70%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <canvas id="amperageChart" width="300em" height="300em" aria-label="ampLabel" role="img"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="chart-container">
            <canvas id="cartesianChart" width="300em" height="300em"></canvas>
            <canvas id="wattageChart" width="300em" height="300em" aria-label="wattLabel" role="img"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

All of them have their unique canvas.
The problem arises when trying to add data to each of them individually since the data is updated in all of them since, basically, all of the data is updated in everyone of them instead for them to take only the data assigned to them.

This is how the updating is done:

```
    console.log("Update for voltage: " + volt);
currentVoltChart.data.labels.pop();
currentVoltChart.data.datasets[0].data.pop();
currentVoltChart.data.labels.unshift(0);
currentWattChart.data.datasets[0].data.unshift(volt);
for(let i = 1; i < currentWattChart.data.labels.length; i++) {
    currentWattChart.data.labels[i] = currentWattChart.data.labels[i] - 1;
}
currentVoltChart.update();
```

This is how the charts are instantiated: (using initialData and initialLabels for everyone of them)

```
let initialData = new Array(10).fill(0);
let initialLabels = ['0', '-1', '-2', '-3', '-4', '-5', '-6', '-7', '-8', '-9'];

currentAmpChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('amperageChart').getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: initialLabels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'mAmpers',
            data: initialData,
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(196, 34, 83, 0.8)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(196, 34, 83, 0.8)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            tension: 0.2
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                max: 1.0
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Doing in this manner so new data is pushed from the origin and the time-passing effect is produced with elements moving to the right.

I don`t even know what to try. Seeing them 3 being individual and not sharing the same canvas should make the job, right? Also, I`m doing this on a raspberry pi using this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"The problem arises when trying to add data to each of them individually since the data is updated in all of them since, basically, all of the data is updated in everyone of them instead for them to take only the data assigned to them."* -- can you please clarify this sentence?

Comment: And I think we will need to see more of the code.

Comment: @GregBurghardt ok, so basically I have a similar method to the the job of updating with new data for the volt/amp/watt charts individually, so 3 methods designated for every chart. If I use 2 of them to update 2 charts (do not matter which one) with 5 and 0.5 values, both the charts have the 5 and 0.5. Instead, the first chart should have only the 5s and the second chart should have only 0.5 values.

Comment: hah...got the problem. the initialData array that was used was basically the storage for all of them instead of what i thought to be their data field as used above.  closing this topic.

Comment: You can answer your own question. There is nothing wrong with that. And you can even mark it as the answer. It might help people with similar problems in the future.